# Is it necessary to bind a real-time thread to an LWP?

Tags: operating-system

We know that an operating system maps user-level threads to the kernel
using the many-to-many model and that the mapping is done through
the use of LWPs. Furthermore, the system allows program developers to
create real-time threads. So, Is it necessary to bind a real-time thread to an
LWP?

Comment: No, we don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

This—

> We know that an operating system maps user-level threads to the kernel using the many-to-many model and that the mapping is done through the use of LWPs.

—is COMPLETELY AND TOTALLY wrong. The entire concept of mapping user threats to kernel threads is entirely the creation of horrible books on operating system and does not exist in the real world (at least in the mainstream).

There is no such thing as a user thread. What horrible textbooks call a "user thread" is a thread simulated by a library. So there is no real point in covering user threads in operating systems at all because they do not exist in the operating system.

Thus, there are threads and there are simulated threads. Outside of horrible textbooks, there is no one to one model, many to many model, or anything like that.

Comment: Yeah - the sea of utter trash that appears in textbooks and tutorial sites is depressing.  It often seems that multithreading advice is given by developers who have never written anything  but single-thread in line code:((